# Updating tabula-py to recent version

Tags: python, pip, updates, tabula

Recently java has released a version that disrupted my development on tabula-py, do you know how to upgrade tabula to the latest version?

> Ex: pip update tabula-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install --upgrade tabula-py
```

See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/ and https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/